# extjs4 treepanel childnode editing

Tags: extjs4

In extjs4 , I would like to click treepanel child node, you can directly edit , and update , but I have no way to do for a long time ,. I am trying a lot on this issue.Please help me.

Help would be appreciated.

Regards,
fange

Answer (score 1):

Oh ... ... I solve this problem, in the "plugins" to add plug- in `Ext.create ('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {clicksToEdit: 2 ,})",`
 most important thing is there must be `Ext.override (Ext.data . AbstractStore, {indexOf: Ext.emptyFn});`